# Rename the "Enter your address to view shipping options" in WooCommerce checkout page under "Your Order"

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I want to rename the text that says "Enter your address to view shipping options." in the WooCommerce checkout page right at the bottom where the "Your Order" section was located.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to replace the default "Enter your address to view shipping options." text to something else, i am not good in woocommerce coding but i have a code snippet plugin installed that will aid me in customizing the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit on file templates/cart/cart-shipping.php
search text "Enter your address to view shipping options."

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better workaround to use filters instead of modifying template files. add this block to the very end of you function.php file in your active theme folder:

```php
add_filter('gettext', 'Behrooz_woo_translations', 20, 3);
add_filter('ngettext', 'Behrooz_woo_translations', 20, 3);
function Behrooz_woo_translations( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
        
    // Put your custom text here in a key => value pair
    $custom_text = array(
        'Enter your address to view shipping options.' => 'This is the text that you want to replace with the original Text.',
    );

    if( array_key_exists( $translation, $custom_text ) ) {
        $translation = $custom_text[$translation];
    }
    return $translation;
}
```